# xamarin.forms listview Items only update when scrolling even after iNotifyPropertychanged implementation

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which have a listview showing item fetched from firebase. The issue I am facing is well asked question in SO ie; one of my item in listview (an item named location ) only updates when we scroll the listview. I tried to implement the `iNotifyPropertychanged` but still I am facing the same issue. What is the mistake I am doing here? Any help is appriciated.

**My Listview Itemsource setting**

```
var person = await firebaseHelper.GetPerson(EmployeeID);// getting data from firebase
                    LocationData = person.userdata.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == StartDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") && x.Longitude != "initial").ToList();
                    ObservableCollection<UserLocationData> dynamicLocation = new ObservableCollection<UserLocationData>(LocationData);
                    TrackingListView.ItemsSource = dynamicLocation;
                    if (dynamicLocation.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (UserLocationData Item in dynamicLocation)
                        {
                            Item.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Item.DateTime).ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm tt");

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.Latitude) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.Longitude))
                            {

                                var Locations = await Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(Convert.ToDouble(Item.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(Item.Longitude));
                                var placemark = Locations?.FirstOrDefault();
                                if (placemark.Thoroughfare.ToString() != null)
                                {
                                    var geocodeAddress =
                                    placemark.Thoroughfare + '\n' +
                                    placemark.SubAdminArea + '\n';
                                    Item.Location = geocodeAddress.ToString();                                  
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Item.Location = Item.Latitude + "," + Item.Longitude;

                                }
                            }

                        }
```

**My Datamodel**

```
 public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }       
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
        public List<UserLocationData> userdata { get; set; }
    }



 public partial class UserLocationData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string DateTime { get; set; }


        private string _location;
        public string Location
        {
            get
            {
                return _location;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    _location = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");
                }
            }
        }


        public bool ButtonOn { get; set; }
        public bool ButtonOff { get; set; }
    }
```

**The Firebase GetPerson portion**

```
   public async Task<Person> GetPerson(string personId)
        {
                var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
                await firebase
                .Child("Persons")
                .OnceAsync<Person>();
                return allPersons.Where(a => a.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault(); 

        }
```

**My XAML**

```
 <ListView  x:Name="TrackingListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding} " 
                             HasUnevenRows="True" 
                             IsVisible="False"
                             CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"                                          
                             SeparatorVisibility="None"   
                             SelectionMode="None"
                             BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
                             Margin="10,10,10,10"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"    
                             >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>

                                        <Frame
                            Padding="5"
                            Margin="0,5,0,5"
                            Opacity="0.9"                           
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            BorderColor="LightBlue"
                            HasShadow="True"                           
                            CornerRadius="10"                          
                            ClassId="{Binding DateTime}"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0" >

                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">


                                                    <Image Source="clock.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                                                       HeightRequest="20" Margin="10,0,5,0"                                                      
                                                       ></Image>

                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                                        <Label Text="Location fetched time" FontSize="12"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                       TextColor="Blue" 

                                                       ></Label>

                                                        <Label Text="{Binding DateTime}"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                       TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"

                                                       ></Label>

                                                    </StackLayout>

                                                </StackLayout>


                                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                    <Image Source="googlemap.png" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" ></Image>

                                                </StackLayout>


                                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">


                                                    <Image Source="currentlocation.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                                                       HeightRequest="20" Margin="10,0,5,0"                                                      
                                                       ></Image>

                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                                        <Label Text="Location " FontSize="12"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                       TextColor="Blue" 

                                                       ></Label>

                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Location}"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                       TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"

                                                       ></Label>

                                                    </StackLayout>

                                                </StackLayout>

                                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="0" >
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0"   IsVisible="{Binding ButtonOn}">

                                                            <Image Source="start.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                                    HeightRequest="20" Margin="10,0,5,0"       
                                                                   VerticalOptions="Start">

                                                            </Image>

                                                            <Label Text="Location Tracking Started" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Green" FontSize="12" ></Label>

                                                        </StackLayout>

                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0"  IsVisible="{Binding ButtonOff}">

                                                            <Image Source="stop.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                                    HeightRequest="20" Margin="10,0,5,0"       
                                                                   VerticalOptions="Start">

                                                            </Image>

                                                            <Label Text="Location Tracking Stopped" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Red" FontSize="12" ></Label>

                                                        </StackLayout>

                                                    </Grid>

                                                </StackLayout>


                                            </Grid>
                                        </Frame>

                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: How do you get the location data? Using Firebase database? Try to set the ListView Itemsource after the if statement. Based on my test with get the data in firebase database and set the ItemSource in the end, it works well for me.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT BRo. Thanks for reply. I can get the data from firebase everytime.No issue with that. Actually I am getting a latitude and longitude from firebase and I try to comvert it into address and bind it to "Item.Location". The problem is first time data will show properly, If we reload the list, the location parameter will not shows. It will show only when we scroll. When I put debugger, it shows the data everytime. But not painting on listview

Comment: Got it. i would test with that, and feedback ASAP.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thanks bro...

Comment: I make the code to get the persons data from firebase and combine Longitude and Latitude into Location. Could you provide the xaml about how to binding Location in Listview? Have you try to reset the ItemSource of ListView? What is the item of the description `one of my item in listview `? Do you mean when add the data to firebase the ListViwe would not update after scrolled?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I added the XAML. I am not resetting the Itemsource. I am getting issue only at the parameter  "Location"  which is the latitude and longitude converted to address,. The problem is when we load the listview first time, all the data will be shows. But when we reload the listview (I am reloading through button click) the location value will not painted. It will shows as blank. As soosn as we scroll the listview, it will appear. That is the issue

Comment: It is atrange. I could not reproduce. I make the similar code sample. In the screenshot, it shows the Location in the Listview at the bottom. When i add the data, the listview would update by resetting the itemsource. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/beggIkP If you wanna do this, i could share the source code.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Can you share the code?

Comment: `NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");` it should be `NotifyPropertyChanged("Location");`

Comment: @Anand You could check the source code in the link below: https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/Firebase_RealTime_Database/FirebaseDatabase/XamarinFirebase And replace the `FirebaseClient` link in FirebaseHelper with your own firebase database link.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Bro thanks for the help. The issue was highlighted by Prateek. I mistakenly added NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");. It should be NotifyPropertyChanged("Location");

Comment: @Prateek Thanks bro. It solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");` it should be `NotifyPropertyChanged("Location");`